# Yii2 Basic Upload multiple images while creating a content

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to upload multiple images when I create a Post, but only one Image is stored in database, in server all images are saved but in my table only first image is saved but not all so I created function for upload

```
// Function to upload images
public function CreateGallery($model_Post, $model_Gallery)
{
    $model_Post->Post_id = md5(microtime());
    $model_Post->User_id = Yii::$app->user->id;

    $GLRID = md5(uniqid());

    // file
    $GFolder = 'upload/images/'. $model_Post->Post_id .'/' ;

    mkdir ($GFolder, 0777, true);

    if ( $model_Post->save() ){

        $model_Gallery->GalleryFile = UploadedFile::getInstances($model_Gallery, 'GalleryFile');

        $ly_GalName = uniqid();

        foreach ($model_Gallery->GalleryFile as $GalleryImage) {

            ++$ly_GalName;
            $model_Gallery->Gallery_id = ++$GLRID;
            $model_Gallery->User_id = $model_Post->User_id;
            $model_Gallery->Post_id =  $model_Post->Post_id;

            $GalleryImage->saveAs($GFolder . $GalName . '.' . $GalleryImage->extension);

            $model_Gallery->Gallery_image = $GFolder . $GalName . '.' . $GalleryImage->extension;
        }
        $model_Gallery->save(false);
    }   
}
```

and inside my controller I add the function I created

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model_Post = new Post(); 
    $model_Gallery = new Gallery;
    $actions_UploadImages = new ActionsUploadImages();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

        $actions_UploadImages->CreateGallery($model_Post, $model_Gallery)

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model_Post->Post_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model_Post' => $model_Post,
            'model_Gallery' => $model_Gallery,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and my views/create my code is

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model_Post, 'Post_title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model_Gallery, 'GalleryFile[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model_Post, 'Post_text')->textarea(['rows' => 2]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model_Post, 'Permission_id')->dropdownList($model_Permission->PermissionList()) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model_Post->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model_Post->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I tried to change gallery_id to AUTO_INCREMENT but still the same problem, I tried to remove if ( $model_Post->save() ), but I get error from database. Only like it's is now it's save all images on server but in table save only one image.

//// gallery model :

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "gallery".
 *
 * @property string $Gallery_id
 * @property string $Gallery_image
 * @property string $Post_id
 * @property string $User_id
 *
 * @property Post $post
 * @property Userlogin $user
 */
class Gallery extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $GalleryFile;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'gallery';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['Gallery_id', 'Post_id', 'User_id'], 'required'],
            [['Gallery_id'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
            [['Gallery_image'], 'string', 'max' => 350],
            [['Post_id', 'User_id'], 'string', 'max' => 300],
            [['GalleryFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg, gif', 'maxFiles' => 5],
            [['Post_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Post::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['Post_id' => 'Post_id']],
            [['User_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Userlogin::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['User_id' => 'User_id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'Gallery_id' => 'Gallery ID',
            'Gallery_image' => 'Gallery Image',
            'Post_id' => 'Post ID',
            'User_id' => 'User ID',
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPost()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Post::className(), ['Post_id' => 'Post_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Userlogin::className(), ['User_id' => 'User_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @return \app\queries\GalleryQuery the active query used by this AR class.
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        return new \app\queries\GalleryQuery(get_called_class());
    }
}
```

Comment: what error does it prints please add the eaxct exception or model error that it displays

Comment: The error it says : Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: add your gallery model

Comment: I did add my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need write  a new model en the for each , like that

**Function**

- Create a new model object in the for each .
- Set the  `$model_Gallery->save(false);`  in inside the foreach

  // Function to upload images

  ```
  public function CreateGallery($model_Post, $model_Gallery)
  {
      $model_Post->Post_id = md5(microtime());
      $model_Post->User_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
      $GLRID = md5(uniqid());
      // file
      $GFolder = 'upload/images/' . $model_Post->Post_id . '/';

      mkdir($GFolder, 0777, true);

      if ($model_Post->save()) {
          $model_Gallery->GalleryFile = UploadedFile::getInstances($model_Gallery, 'GalleryFile');

          $ly_GalName = uniqid();

          foreach ($model_Gallery->GalleryFile as $GalleryImage) {
              $model_GalleryImage = new Gallery;
              ++$ly_GalName;
              $model_GalleryImage->Gallery_id = ++$GLRID;
              $model_GalleryImage->User_id = $model_Post->User_id;
              $model_GalleryImage->Post_id = $model_Post->Post_id;

              $GalleryImage->saveAs($GFolder . $GalName . '.' . $GalleryImage->extension);

              $model_GalleryImage->Gallery_image = $GFolder . $GalName . '.' . $GalleryImage->extension;
              $model_GalleryImage->save(false); //here , remove 'false' to work validations
          }

      }
  }
  ```

**Controller**

when the action load the data  ,it should not be like that ?

```
if ($model_Gallery->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) and  $model_Post->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        //the rest of the code
        }
```

> Please note that we use save(false) to skip over validations inside the models as the user input data... with the user input

Comment: skipping validations is not the solution to the problem you need to validate each image before you insert/save it otherwise the files that are not supported will also be allowed to be uploaded

Comment: I know but he wrote it that way, I prefer save () whitout false

Comment: I did try this this solution but still not working not save all images on database , but it's save them all on server but not on table

Comment: I have made some changes, create the model within the loop, and possible change in the controller in the data load @Bynd

Comment: it's working with making the $model_GalleryImage = new Gallery;
and remove it from controller. You are genius.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is iterate $_FILES object using foreach loop and create new model every time. To validate code manage flag for that

Comment: "All you have to do is iterate $_FILES", I don't know how to do it. But this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/49553996/6562828 work.